# "Administer Web Site" equivalent for IIS deployment

Tags: asp.net, iis

During development, i can easily manage my users/roles/smtp etc using the "Administer Web Site" or "ASP.net configuration "command in Visual Studio. Once the site is deployed to a IIS server, How can i get the same functionality (user and role management).

I am using IIS 6

## Edit 1

My Server doesnt have the web server executable mentioned in the blog post (JP's response). So i copied it from my dev machine. but it still isnt working. The server is crashing with error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or ass
embly 'WebDev.WebHost, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f
11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IIS admin tools will be available on the production server as well.  [Here is a blog post](http://blogs.neudesic.com/blogs/phil_scott/archive/2006/07/04/187.aspx) on the ASP.NET config. web site.

Edit for comment:

I don't think you can just copy the exe over.  I think you need to at least install [visual web developer](http://www.microsoft.com/express/download/).  That will ensure that all the dependencies are installed as well.